# Parsing json string crashes

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to parse a json string:

```
if let jsonStr = asd.value(forKey: "orderData") as? String {
    print(jsonStr)

    let data = jsonStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject] // CRASHES HERE
        if let names = json["product_name"] as? [String] {
            print(names)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

But at the line `let json = try JSONSeri...` it crashes saying `Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' to 'NSDictionary'.`

Also tried changing this `as! [String: AnyObject]` to `as! [[String: AnyObject]]`. But it still doesn't work.

This is my json string structure:

```
[
  {
    "product_id" : "1",
    "category_json" : {
      "category_id" : "1",
      "category_name" : "nvm"
    },
    "selling_price" : "200",
    "product_name" : "nvm",
  },

 {
    "product_id" : "2",
    "category_json" : {
      "category_id" : "2",
      "category_name" : "cas"
    },
    "selling_price" : "800",
    "product_name" : "cas",
  }
]
```

Comment: Your JSON is an Array at topLevel, not a Dictionary. `as! [String: AnyObject]` mean Dictionary with all key being Strings. So it's normal that it crashes with that error message. `as! [[String: AnyObject]]` should work, but then it's an array, so you clearly can't do `json["product_name"]` on it.

Comment: Ok @Larme so how it should have been...?

Comment: yes..you are right @Larme..so what should have been done instead..?

Comment: Please **read** the JSON: Array: JSON `[]`, code `[[String:Any]]`, Dictionary: JSON `{}`, code `[String:Any]`

Comment: https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be force casting with ! unless you are 100% sure that it will succeed.

I would suggest you use the following:

```
let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]]
```

This will return you a list of products. If you want a list of the product names than you need to iterate over it and extract the product name of each item. You can do this like so:

```
let names = jsonArray.map({ $0["product_name"] as? String })
```

Comment: this won't work @Scriptable because if we do this then in the very next line it shows an error saying `Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'`

Comment: @bvt it will work, your JSON is an array of dictionaries. So it is a list. you need to select an item from the list.

Comment: But @Scriptable it shows the error I mentioned in this line`if let names = json["product_name"] as? [String]`

Comment: if let names = json["product_name"] as? String and not [String]

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the object is an array, you have to use a for loop to get all items

```
 ...
   let data = Data(jsonStr.utf8)

   do {
       if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {
           for item in json {
               if let name = item["product_name"] as? String {
                   print(name)
               }
           }
       }
   } catch {
       print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
```

Comment: `item["product_name"] as? [String]` will not be an array. it will be a String

Comment: Thanks @vadian in fact both answers worked..But accepted the other one since it was first given..But have given an upvote though..:)